# Choosing integers $(a,b,c,d)$ such that $0\le a\le b\le c\le d\le n$

Tags: combinatorics

I feel like I have got the main part of this problem solved but I'm struggling to seal the deal.

Given a positive integer $n$ find the number of quadruples of $(a,b,c,d)$ such that $0\le a\le b\le c\le d\le n$

I can simplify the problem by choosing 4 integers on $[0,n]$ then putting them in ascending order afterwards. There are $n+1$ ways to choose one integer on this interval, so there are $(n+1)^4$ ways to choose 4 not necessarily distinct integers, therefore eliminating the duplicates of each permutation we have $\frac{(n+1)^4}{4!}$ ways of doing this.

However, this is an integer iff n is even, so cannot be right.

Please comment any duplicates to this, it's a very hard question to google.

Answer (score 1):

You have done the wrong approach. The right approach is to let $x_1=a-0$, $x_2=b-a$, $x_3=c-b$, $x_4=d-c$ and $x_5=n-d$. This forms a bijection between the quadruples $(a,b,c,d)$ and the number of nonnegative solutions to $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=n$, which by stars and bars is $\binom{n+4}4$.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than looking for tuples $(a,b,c,d)$ instead look for tuples $(v,w,x,y,z)$ where $v = a, w = b-a, x=c-b, y=d-c$ and $z=n-d$

You should be able to see that counting the number of integer solutions to $\begin{cases}0\leq a\leq b\leq c\leq d\leq n\end{cases}$ is equivalent to counting the number of integer solutions to $$\begin{cases}v+w+x+y+z=n\\ 0\leq v\\0\leq w\\0\leq x\\0\leq y\\0\leq z\end{cases}$$

To solve this, apply [stars-and-bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach: look at the numbers $A=a+1, B=b+2, C=c + 3, D=d+4$.

The original requirements translate exactly to $1\leq A< B < C < D \leq n+4$, hence the answer is simply to choose $4$ different numbers from $\{1,2,\dots,n+4\}$.